# Using rand() to simulate dice. Slightly lost

Tags: c

This is probably a stupid question, but I'm really struggling with this concept. I'm going through a tutorial explaining about arrays and the rand() function. I have two problems. 

The first is, obviously to simulate one dice we need to randomly generate a number from 1-6. The book suggests this:

```
int       RollOne( void ) {
    return (rand() % 6) + 1;
}
```

Right, well rand() can generate any number from 0-32767. We then find the remainder of this number when it's divided by 6, then add 1. E.g. 3245 is randomly generated. We divide it by 6, giving 540.8333 and take the remainder. 8.333 (truncated to 8 I believe) and then add 1. Unless I'm going mad, that makes 9, which is not between 1-6. The program runs fine however and I just can't understand how we get a number from 1-6 using that code! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The second problem I have isn't really as major, but is relevant. The book left out what this bit of code means:

```
srand( clock() );
```

All that is mentioned is that srand() initialises a random number generator using the seed provided by clock(). Right, now can we actually input anything into clock(), if so what is its effect? Just a little explanation of what srand( clock() ) does would be perfect.

Sorry for the long post, I hope you don't mind the wall'o'text. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

**ANSWERED**
Thank you everyone: I realise what I was doing. As shown by you guys, the % operator doesn't divide, it just finds the difference between the highest multiple and the operand. Got it! I was under the impression that the remainder meant the decimal. I.e. If 7/2 = 3.5 then the remainder is 0.5. Now that I've written it out, I see how stupid I've been. Glad my A-level maths counts for something.....
Thanks again!

Comment: How can the remainder be 8.3333?? 6 goes into 8.33333 so the remainder should be 2.3333

Comment: The quotient and modulus are operations on (mathematical) integers, and connot give 8.333 or any non-integer number!

Comment: You might want to re-check your math, the "remainder" of any division should always be an integer, and never be greater than the divisor

Comment: I think you did something wrong because `3245 % 6 = 5 + 1 = 6`

Comment: Your remainder is 5, not 8.333, add one and you get 6, which is a totally valid result

Comment: It's not a stupid question. In fact, I'd say it's a damn good question. You tersely explain your situation, provide the code you're working on, explain the expected behavior, walk through the steps you believe is happening, and clearly state the problem. Sure, it's a simple question, but it's a fantastically well-asked question.

Comment: I think you made a mistake there, `srand(clock())` is not a good way to seed the random number generator. I think you meant `srand(time(NULL))`.

Comment: Thanks Philip. Lie Ryan, what difference does it make if they both use the time as a seed? I shall start using `time(NULL)` from now on though.

Comment: Clock is not measuring time, clock measures the length of time (or more precisely, the number of clock ticks) that have passed since you started your program, if you called srand early in your program, there is a pretty large chance that you will be calling clock around a certain number of clock tick, and you will get an unusually high chance of getting a number sequence that you already get in some previous runs of the program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 3245 is randomly generated. We divide it by 6, giving 540.8333 and
>   take the remainder.

You are confused between integer truncation and remainders.  When you divide 3245 by 6 using integer math the remainder is 5 (or 0.83333 * 6 = 5).

Another way to see this is 540 * 6 = 3240, which leaves a remainder of 5.

Comment: Yup, a stupid mistake in hindsight. Thanks. Explained really clearly, hence answer given.

Answer (score 8):

Your example is slightly incorrect:

If you generated 3245 randomly, dividing it by 6 yields 540.8333 (because of integer math you actually get 540). The remainder is then 3245 - 6 * 540, which is 5. 5+1 is 6 :D

Comment: Yup, realise this now. It's almost embarrassing that I didn't notice! Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 4):

***How rand(clock()) works***

The seed is just a number to start working from.

There is actually no such thing as random in computers (just the illusion of randomness), everything is a complex calculation/transformation involving the seed, you just need a number to start with (the seed) which comes from the system clock in this case as it is always changing and should always provide random-like results.

You can probably put any value you want where the system clock value goes. Just don't expect good randomness to occur.

**Again, clock() is usually used as it is a value that is constantly changing.**

Just think of it, you should never have the same value from system clock twice. There's always some passage of time and the difference could be a millisecond or less, but even though the change could be small it's a different time than a nanosecond ago.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation of rand( clock() ). Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

To your second question, srand is used to seed the random number generator. Computers can't really generate truly random numbers without some specialized hardware, so what we do is we uses a mathematical function like the [Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) (used by many C standard library as the default algorithm) or [Mersenne Twister](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) which produces a series of number that are highly unpredictable, this mathematical function has to be seeded to give it the first "random" value. A good seed value will be something which is different for every run of the program, time is good as long as you don't run the same program twice in the same second. The reason you need to seed is because pseudo random number function isn't really random, if you give the function the same seed, the function will return the exact same sequence of numbers every time (which can be useful for certain kind of simulations, but most of the time you want every run to be different).

Exercise:

> Run this program:
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int main() {
>     srand(1234);
>     for (int i=0; i < 20; i++) 
>         printf("%d ", rand());
>     printf("\n");
> }
> ```
>
> several time and observe what happens, then replace 1234 with
>   time(NULL) and observe what happens. Write a shell script that runs
>   the modified program several times very quickly, and observe what
>   happens.

Comment: Thank you for adding even more, on top of the previous answers. The example is great. Really interesting!

Answer (score 0):

How can the remainder be 8? Surely that would mean that 6 would go into it one more time? % is also not the divide function it is the div function which is different.

Answer (score 0):

Percent doesn't divide. It gives the remainder (the 'mod' function).